# is it possible in BigQuery to generate a Minimum bounding geometry by attribute?

Tags: google-bigquery

is it possible using the new announced function ST_CONVEXHULL to generate a polygon from an array of points see this example

```
WITH Geographies AS
  (SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POINT(1 1)') AS g ,'polygon' as t UNION ALL
   SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POINT(1 3)') AS g ,'polygon' as t UNION ALL
   SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POINT(1 2)') AS g ,'polygon' as t         )
SELECT 
  t, ST_CONVEXHULL(g) AS polygon FROM Geographies group by 1;
```

Bigquery gave me an error as ST_CONVEXHULL is not an aggregate function, it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
WITH Geographies AS
  (SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POINT(1 1)') AS g ,'polygon' as t UNION ALL
   SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POINT(2 3)') AS g ,'polygon' as t UNION ALL
   SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT('POINT(1 2)') AS g ,'polygon' as t         
)
SELECT ST_CONVEXHULL(ST_UNION_AGG(g)) AS polygon 
FROM Geographies
```

As you can see, first you need to "collect" all geo objects using ST_UNION_AGG() function

Below is result along with initial points

[image]

Comment: should I add a separate question , what if I group by polygon, and polygon1

Comment: have you posted that new question? i didn't see  it

Comment: Sorry, gound the

Comment: Thanks,  found the solution